# React native overlapped rendering issue

Tags: list, listview, reactjs, react-native, rendering

## Overlapped rendering

I'm using react native to build a list of `Notifications`, but I sometimes have an issue like the image below.

When refreshing/adding data I sometimes get overlapped rendering where old data is displayed on top of new data.

I've added the `key` property on the `ListItem` in the `renderRow` method as described in the docs.

Anyone knows a fix or why this is happening?

Kind regards

[image: Overlapped rendering]